# xml has two buttons but pop up dialog only has one

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-xml

My pop up dialog xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tastePickTitle"
        android:text="Select a Taste: "
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle = "bold"
        android:padding="5dip"
        >
    </TextView>

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:entries="@array/taste_array"

         />

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp">
    </View>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ammountPickTitle"
        android:text="How much taste: "
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle = "bold"
        android:padding="5dip"
        >
    </TextView>

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:entries="@array/ammount_array"

         />

    <LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

     <Button
        android:id="@+id/addTasteButton"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Add"
        android:onClick="addTasteNow" />

     <Button
        android:id="@+id/cancelButton"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Cancel"
        android:onClick="cancelTaste" />


     </LinearLayout>




</LinearLayout>
```

But when I look at the pop up dialog it shows like this:

[image]

I want both buttons next to each other.

Comment: Have you tried changing `android:orientation="vertical"` to `android:orientation="horizontal"`?

Comment: it is horizontal, look at the code

Comment: I did look at the code...I thought you meant the `Spinners` next to each other. You have `android:layout_width="fill_parent"` for your first `Button`. It should be `wrap_content` or use `weight`s

Comment: You've set the `layout_width` of both buttons to `fill_parent`. Change the `layout_width` of both to be `0dp` then add `layout_weight="1"` to both of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `android:layout_width="fill_parent"` for your first Button. It should be `wrap_content` or use `weight`s. Your first `Button` is taking up all of the available space. If they are `wrap_content` then they will take up the space they need. If you want them to have an even amount of space then you can do something like give the `LinearLayout` parent a `weightSum` of 2 and give each a `weight` of 1. When you use `weight`s set `layout_width` to 0dp for a `horizontal orientation` and `height` to 0 dp for a `vertical orientation`

so your `LinearLayout` for your `Button`s may look like

```
<LinearLayout 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:weightSum="2" >

 <Button
    android:id="@+id/addTasteButton"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Add"
    android:onClick="addTasteNow"
    android:weight="1" />

 <Button
    android:id="@+id/cancelButton"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Cancel"
    android:onClick="cancelTaste"
    android:weight="1" />
 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Using `weightSum` isn't generally necessary - it's calculated from the total of the weights and apportioned based on their percentages.

Comment: @Squonk only necessary if you want `View`s weighted differently and not all proportionally the same, correct?

Comment: No, you can leave out `weightSum` and have weights of (for example) 1, 4, 5. The calculated weight sum will be 10 and the respective views will get 1/10, 4/10 and 5/10 of the width/height depending on layout orientation. Or, in other words, 10%, 40% and 50%.

Comment: Ok, so when would `weightSum` need to be determined by the programmer? In other words, what would be a case that I would actually need to set that property?

Comment: To be honest, I don't know and have never figured it out. Perhaps it was necessary for older versions of Android or perhaps it's needed if some views are "gone" or "invisible" but the documentation isn't clear. It's possible that specifying a `weightSum` of 10 and having 2 views with (for example) weights of 3 & 5 would allow a blank space equal to 2 without a view needing to occupy that space.

Comment: @Squonk ok, thank you for your honesty and opinions. Now I don't feel so bad for not fully understanding it! Ha! But that was helpful...now I know the way I was thinking about it wasn't necessarily wrong but not needed either. Thanks

Comment: Sure - your thinking wasn't wrong and perhaps it may be better to include `weightSum` just for completeness and code checking in a collaborative project even it isn't needed. One day I might find out what `weightSum` is for and when it's needed - if I do I'll let you know. :D

Comment: weightSum can be useful if you want a View to occupy for instance 50% of the available space. Create a LinearLayout with a weightSum of 1.0, add a single child, give it a width of 0 and a weight of 0.5 and you'll get that effect. You could also have to children using only 25% of the available space left each, etc.

Comment: @Squonk did you see Romain Guy's comment? So, as you were saying, I guess it isn't needed if you want to take up the complete parent layout

Comment: @codeMagic : Thanks for drawing my attention to it. So that fits the last scenario a couplle of comments back (sum of 10 and two views with 3 & 5 leaving 20% space). Now we know. :D

Comment: @RomainGuy : Thanks for the clarification. I've always used `layout_weight` to apportion total space amongst all views which is why I never worked out what the correct use of `weightSum` is.

Comment: @Squonk, you're welcome. Really appreciate the quick response from RomainGuy. I've always done the same but always used `weightSum` just to be safe and, as you said, for completeness.

Comment: I would trust a CPU more than myself to come up with the right weight sum :)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try to add the buttons in a linearlayout?
In any case It should work with your code too... I'm curious to know why it doesn't too...
I'm sorry for my english but I hope I can help you.
This is my solution (insert two buttons in LinearLayout):

```
  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/addTasteButton"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="addTasteNow"
        android:text="Add" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/cancelButton"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="cancelTaste"
        android:text="Cancel" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: They are already in a single `LinearLayout`. This just creates an extra unnecessary `LinearLayout`

Comment: I know this is not the best pactice but I see some user interface designer to resolve this problem this way. 
I hope it could be useful to solve your problem. 
I'm sorry for my english and I hope I helped you.